# Ruby Method Always reset the number

Tags: ruby

I have this method here that basically counts player wins and computer wins.

```
def increment_winner(player, computer)

    player_count = 0
    computer_count = 0

    if win?(player, computer)
      player_count+=1
    elsif win?(computer, player)
      computer_count+=1
    end

    prompt("Player Count: #{player_count}")
    prompt("Computer Count: #{computer_count}")

end
```

I tried to use to call it via:

```
increment_winner(choice, computer_choice)
```

But each time I call the game it always reset the number of counts to zero.

Here's my whole code:

```
WINNING_COMBO = {
  'r' => ['sc', 'l'],
  'p' => ['r', 'sp'],
  'sc' => ['p', 'l'],
  'l' => ['sp', 'p'],
  'sp' => ['sc', 'r']
}

def win?(first, second)
  WINNING_COMBO[first].include?(second)
end


def display_results(player, computer)
  if win?(player, computer)
    prompt("You won this round!")
  elsif win?(computer, player)
    prompt("Computer won this round! You loose!")
  else
    prompt("It's a tie on this round! No one wins!")
  end
end

def increment_winner(player, computer)

    player_count = 0
    computer_count = 0

    if win?(player, computer)
      player_count+=1
    elsif win?(computer, player)
      computer_count+=1
    end

    prompt("Player Count: #{player_count}")
    prompt("Computer Count: #{computer_count}")

end

  loop do # main loop
    choice = ''
    loop do
      prompt("Choose a key:")
      VALID_CHOICES.each do |short_name, complete_name|
        prompt("'#{short_name}' for #{complete_name}")
      end
      choice = Kernel.gets().chomp().downcase()

      if VALID_CHOICES.include?(choice)
        break
      else
        prompt("That's not a valid choice.")
      end
    end

    computer_choice = VALID_CHOICES.keys.sample
    display_results(choice, computer_choice)
    increment_winner(choice, computer_choice)
    prompt("Do you want to play again? ('yes' or 'no')")

  loop do  
    answer = Kernel.gets().chomp()
    if answer.casecmp('yes').zero?
      break
    elsif answer.casecmp('no').zero?
      prompt("Thank you for playing!\n  Have a nice day! Good bye!")
      exit
    else
      prompt("Please enter either 'yes' or 'no'.")
    end

  end

  end
```

Any idea how can I improve the method so it will not reset the count? If it's not possible, how can I use it within the loop? How can I know w/c variable to use to know which is the winner?

NOTE: I don't want to use instance or global variable here as it is for object oriented.

Comment: you have defined `player_count = 0` inside `increment_winner` method so whenever this method call it set zero, set these two variable as instance variable or global variable out of the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the initial values to the function:

```
def increment_winner(player, computer, counts)
    if win?(player, computer)
      counts[:player] += 1
    elsif win?(computer, player)
      counts[:computer] += 1
    end

    prompt("Player Count: #{counts[:player]}")
    prompt("Computer Count: #{counts[:computer]}")
end
```

and call this function with the hash param:

```
counts = {player: 0, computer: 0}
loop do # main loop
  ......
  increment_winner(choice, computer_choice, counts)
  ......
end
```

Comment: Hmm...Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [create global variables](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope#Ruby_Global_Variables) by moving the count variables to global scope and prefixing them with a `$`:

```
$player_count = 0
$computer_count = 0

def increment_winner(player, computer)

    if win?(player, computer)
      $player_count+=1
    elsif win?(computer, player)
      $computer_count+=1
    end

    prompt("Player Count: #{$player_count}")
    prompt("Computer Count: #{$computer_count}")

end
```

However, global variables are looked down on, so you can instead make things static locals:

```
def increment_winner(player, computer)

    @player_count ||= 0
    @computer_count ||= 0

    if win?(player, computer)
      @player_count+=1
    elsif win?(computer, player)
      @computer_count+=1
    end

    prompt("Player Count: #{@player_count}")
    prompt("Computer Count: #{@computer_count}")

end
```

This is probably the more Ruby-like solution, although I see from your edit that you don't want this solution!

Comment: how can I do it without the instance or global variable?

Comment: You could, I suppose, read and write from a score file? But why don't you want to use instance or global variables?

Comment: Is it possible to put it inside my loop instead?

Comment: This solution will not work, because you are setting value 0 to the instance variables each time you call the `increment_winner` method.

Comment: I am working on a procedural assignment. Not yet on the OOP part or advance part.

Comment: Global variables are anti-OOP! I suppose the other way would be to use `def increment_winner(player, computer, player_count, computer_count)`?

Comment: Is it possible to insert it inside my loop instead of using global or instance variable?

Comment: @kallax - Oops, fixed!

Comment: how about constants and local variables would that work?